# Django call_command and popen. When to use what?

Tags: python, django, django-views, subprocess, popen

I want to start a command from django management/command from django.view but don't know which one to use. Can some one explain me the properties and differences of both.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what "command" you want to call.

`call_command` is for calling Django management commands only - eg syncdb, runserver, or any custom management commands. It calls the command directly, without shelling out to the system.

`popen` and the various functions in `subprocess` etc are for shelling out to call any other executable file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to use it as Django management commands. Thanks for explaining.